# How to access an object inside an array

Tags: php

I have this small code:

```
$user = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
if ($user->count()) {
    foreach ($user as $users) {
        echo $users->username;
    }
}
var_dump($users);die();
```

This gives me an error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\finaltask\test.php on line 8
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["username"]=> string(10) "reinisk157" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["username"]=> string(9) "reinisk22" } }
```

If I understand correctly, Im trying to retrieve an object from an array, but I have no idea how else to get this data out of my DB. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you share the object? It is saying you do not have an object called `user`

Comment: `$users` is probably not the one you want to loop over or echo from. You could change the db result from `$user` to `$users` and then change your echo to `echo $user->username`. Right now you are getting the `$users` out of nowhere.

Comment: show us `var_dump($user);`

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue of scope and naming here that may confuse you.

Scope of a foreach

```
foreach($list as $item) {
    // ... do something
}
echo $item;
```

When looping through a list/array, the last item of the loop will still be available after the loop. That's why the dump looks like it does, as you are dumping the wrong thing.

```
$userResult = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
if ($userResult->count()) {
    foreach ($userResult as $user) {
        echo $user->username;
    }
}
var_dump($userResult);die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$usersResult = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` and then foreach as you used.

```
$users = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
$usersResult = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if ($usersResult->count()) {
    foreach ($usersResult as $user) {
        echo $user->username;
    }
}
var_dump($usersResult);
die();
```

> Note: I have changed `$users` to `$user` while parsing data in the
>   loop because this makes more sense for individual user's data.

Hope this works!

Comment: This is stbObject - why access like array?

Comment: You are assuming that `Database::getInstance()` returns a PDO Object, at this point it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

First, semantically, with that query you fetch users, not just one user. It's not important when it comes to the code itself, but it's important to understand it :)

```
$users = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
// I prefer is_null over count(), when a query returns 0 rows turns on null
if (!is_null($users)) {
    foreach($users as $user){
        //Try calling it this way
        echo $user['username'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thamks for all the answers, i'll try them as well. The one I made it work was:

```
echo $users[0]->username;
```